# How to print a pound "£" in html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-entities

i am trying to display a pound sign in my html page.i want to display it through a variable because i am getting the values of sign from an xml file.

Here is Code:

```
var sign = $('#currencySign').text();
$('#monthly_Amt').text("\'"+sign+"\'"+monthlypayment);
```

```
<div id="monthly_amt"></div>
<div id="currencySign">\u00A3</div>
```

and the out put is

```
'\u00A3'450.33
```

and i want it as `£450.33`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/coolsohi/kMFLG/)

How can I fix this?

Comment: you have to use &#163

Comment: I've found the issue and updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Jack retract the close vote

Comment: @Mr.Alien oooh shiny new feature!

Comment: @Jack they provided that way back, am using that since 1-2 months *(I guess)*

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`\u00A3`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a3/index.htm) ...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VT2J2/)

Alternatively you can use entity name as `&pound;` or entity number as `&#163;` as well but  you need to use `.html()` and **NOT** <s>`.text()`</s>

And use `var` and not <s>`Var`</s>

---

As you commented, I see you are getting more troubles with this, if you want you can accomplish this easily with CSS like

```
#monthly_amt:before {
    content: "'£'"; /* Or you can use \00a3 instead of £ */
}
```

And your jQuery will be

```
var monthlypayment = 1000;
$('#monthly_amt').text(monthlypayment);
```

And if the element is dynamically generated, you can get rid of it using `.remove()`

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/VT2J2/5/)

Comment: Not sure why you struck out `.text()` ... it now reads: you need to use `.html()` and not not `.text()` =p

Comment: @Jack It's like `===` operator :P strict one haha

Comment: In any case, you don't need `.html()`.

Comment: @Jack weird, I used that cuz that didn't worked for me using `.text()`

Comment: Could you check [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qumorele/1/)? I hope it's not a browser thing :)

Comment: @Jack ok. I got where I confused myself, I used entity with `.text()` which failed... ;) and I edited it out, thanks

Comment: Actually, I ran OP's code and it [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/VT2J2/2/) too, so I'm cv'ing it =/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/coolsohi/kMFLG/   look into this example where i am wrong i am still getting same output

Comment: If the field is empty it would always have a pound symbol prefixed; not sure whether that's desirable; also, there's no reason to use `.html()`.

Comment: @Jack oops, I left it as is, will update the `.html` part and yea he can use `.addClass()` to the elements where the pound is required

Comment: Please don't use `<kbd>` tags to decorate your links. The `<kbd>` element is used to denote user input, not hyperlinks.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Its just ok to do so, and please take care while you edit, you just removed the demo 2 link

Comment: @Mr.Alien it *isn't* okay to do so as it goes against the HTML specification. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181795/211113. Also Demo 2 wasn't (and still isn't) linked properly anyway, I only removed the `<kbd>` tags.

Answer (score 3):

It is:

```
&pound;
```

or

```
&#163;
```

You can check other encodings here:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

And here is a demo on how to do it:
[**Online Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3LrVH/)

```
var sign = "&pound;";
$('#demo').html(sign+124.5);
```

Comment: This will still render the entities as pure text, the OP is using correct thing but he requires `.html()` because `.text()` will fail...

Answer (score 1):

To print a pound symbol, simply ... print the pound symbol:

```
var sign = '£';

$('#monthly_Amt').text(sign + monthlypayment);
```

Or, if that's somehow uncomfortable:

```
var sign = "\u00A3";

$('#monthly_Amt').text(sign + monthlypayment);
```

Or, with the quotes:

```
$('#monthly_Amt').text("'" + sign + "'" + monthlypayment);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/qumorele/1/)

#### Update

It seems that the "variable" actually comes from an HTML element, but `\x00A3` only works in string literals.

This HTML fixes it:

```
<div id="currencySign">&pound;</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kMFLG/1/)

Comment: For `JSON.parse()` you still need the double quoted enclosure :)

Comment: E_TOO_MUCH_TROUBLE :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
£   &pound; &#163;  &#xA3;  Pound Sterling
```

See this Link

```
     http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-cur.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
var sign = '&#163;'
$('#monthly_Amt').html("\'"+sign+"\'"+monthlypayment);
```

For the £ sign use: &#163; (ASCII Code)

http://jsfiddle.net/seckela/7gjF5/

EDIT: Using .text() will render the literal text, .html interprets it as an HTML element and will render special ASCII Characters using the ASCII codes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `&#163`;

```
$(this).text('&amp;#163;');
```

- If you try this and it does not work, just change the jQuery methods,

  $(this).html('&#163;');

This always work in all contexts...

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to look into it.

```
<div id="divResponse">
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
var sign = "\u00A3"
var monthlypayment = "5000"
$('#divResponse').text(sign+monthlypayment);
});
```

here is the fiddle link :
[poundExampleJSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arpitanchal/6K5D8/1/)

If this is helpful to you, please mark it as helpful.

Thanks